# Find matches for the 5th columns in a pipe delim files

Tags: text-processing, columns, join

```
File 1:
Connect|20130320000023|UTC|PPP|test3@test3.co.uk|test1@test1.co.uk|0BCBE578|
File 2:
Connect|20130320000023|UTC|PPP|test1@test1.co.uk|test1@test1.co.uk|0BCBE578|
Connect|20130320000025|UTC|PPP|test2@test2.co.uk|test1@test1.co.uk|0BCBE578|
Connect|20130320000025|UTC|PPP|test3@test3.co.uk|test1@test1.co.uk|0BCBE578|
```

I need to find matching records in both File 1 and File 2 in column 5. So from the above I need to return in the output:

```
Connect|20130320000025|UTC|PPP|test3@test3.co.uk|test1@test1.co.uk|0BCBE578|
```

Many thanks,

Comment: In other words, print lines from `file2` whose 5th column is found in at least one line of `file1` at the 5th column. Correct? I'm asking this because the second column in the matching records doesn't match and you chose to print the `file2` version.

Answer (score 3):

#### Method #1: grep & awk

You can use this snippet to do it:

```
$ grep -f <(awk -F '|' '{print $5}' file1)  file2
Connect|20130320000025|UTC|PPP|test3@test3.co.uk|test1@test1.co.uk|0BCBE578|
```

#### Details

The bit that uses `awk` parses the first file, `file1` pulling out all the 5th columns. These values are then used as a list to `grep`, which will print any lines in the 2nd file that contain a match.

#### Caveats with this method

This method will match any occurrence of the 5th column from `file1` in `file2`.

#### Method #2: Just awk

Another approach that has been used on the site in the past is to use `awk`'s FNR facility. This is where `awk` will iterate over 2 files, going through the second file line by line, for each line in the first.

An approach like this would do it. Put the following into a file, `cmds.awk`:

```
FNR == NR {
f1[$5] = $5
next
}

{ if ($5 == f1[$5]) print $0; }
```

You can then run this as follows:

```
$ awk -F '|' -f cmds.awk file1 file2
```

**NOTE:** You could've used this `awk` pattern instead:

```
FNR == NR {
f1[$5] = $5
next
}

{ if ($5 in f1) print $0; }
```

#### Example

```
$ awk -F '|' -f s.awk file1 file2
Connect|20130320000025|UTC|PPP|test3@test3.co.uk|test1@test1.co.uk|0BCBE578|
```

#### Caveats with this method

This approach can only handle a single instance of each email address from `file1`. So if there are 2 lines that both have the same value for the 5th column, this won't be able to distinguish between them. This seems acceptable given your requirements in the OP though.

#### Join & sort

You can also do this using `join` and `sort`.

```
$ join -t '|' -j 5  <(sort -k5,5 file2) <(sort -k5,5 file1) | sed 's/||.*//'
```

This will use the separator `|` and join the sorted files on the 5th column. This approach prints the matches from both `file1` and `file2`, so we use `sed` to chop the 2nd match off the end.

#### Example

```
$ join -t '|' -j 5  <(sort -k5,5 file2) <(sort -k5,5 file1) | sed 's/||.*//'
test3@test3.co.uk|Connect|20130320000025|UTC|PPP|test1@test1.co.uk|0BCBE578
```

Comment: +1 Careful, though. This will print lines from `file2` containing the data in the 5th column of `file1` _anywhere_.

Comment: @JosephR. - thanks, I'm working out a more explicit version that isn't as loose on the matching as this one.

Comment: @JosephR. - I've added the venerable `FNR==NR` method using `awk` too.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to read about this one some time. I see it a lot in answers around here.

Comment: @JosephR. - Good example of `awk`'s looping constructs: http://www.unixcl.com/2009/01/difference-between-awk-nr-and-fnr.html

Comment: This algorithm's run time is proportional to the *product* of the file sizes. You can do better!

Comment: @sds - a solution using `comm` would be the most efficient but the setup of it can be a bit of a pain, so as long as the data sets we're dealing with are small (100k lines or less, even more than that isn't really an issue either, but drawing a line in the sand) using `awk FNR==NR` is fine.

Comment: @sds - added join/sort method.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the whole thing in perl:

```
$ perl -F'\|' -ane '$k{$F[4]}++; print if $k{$F[4]}>1' file1 file2  
Connect|20130320000025|UTC|PPP|test3@test3.co.uk|test1@test1.co.uk|0BCBE578|
```

- `-a` activates automatic field splitting into the array `@F`.
- `-F'\|'` sets the field delimiter for `-a` to `|`.
- For each line processed, save the 5th field (array indices start at `0` in perl) as a hash key (`$k{$F[4]}++` and increment its value by one. The second time a field is seen, that value will be 2.
- The script will process each line of both files (`file1` before `file2`) and print the line if the 5th field has been seen before, i.e. if `$k{$F[4]}` is greater than one.

This assumes that no fifth column is repeated within the *same* file. If this is not the case and some columns may be duplicated in the same file, use this instead:

```
perl -e 'open(A,"$ARGV[0]"); while(<A>){@F=split(/\|/);$k{$F[4]}++;}
         open(B,"$ARGV[1]"); while(<B>){@F=split(/\|/); print if $k{$F[4]} 
         }' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file sizes are comparable, the optimal solution is to [`sort`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_%28Unix%29) both files by the column you are interested in and then [`join`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28Unix%29) them by that column. If the file sizes are `N` and `M` then the asymptotic run time is `O(N*log(N)+M*log(M))`.

If one of the files is much much smaller than the other, then the `O(N*M)` solution in the other answers is better.

Comment: a solution using comm would be the most efficient but the setup of it can be a bit of a pain, so as long as the data sets we're dealing with are small (100k lines or less, even more than that isn't really an issue either, but drawing a line in the sand) using awk FNR==NR is fine.

Comment: perhaps you could show an example? Sort of put your money where your mouth is. 8-) We typically show how on this site, not just mention potential solutions. You'll find some issues when dealing with join as we've had in the past with questions of this nature. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90214/joining-two-files-with-unique-identifier/90297#90297

Comment: see my answer for an implementation of the join/sort method.